# Load Balancer - Lock wait timeout exceeded - try restarting transaction

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, load-balancing

I have the following architecture:

1 Load balancer

3 Amazon EC 2 instances (LAMP, with Symfony2)

1 RDS Database

I recently set this up, cause i was getting to much traffic for a single instance, and i made Symfony2 use the database for sessions, but now i keep getting this error in the log file:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" at /var/www/front/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php line 513
```

I assume that this is because all instances are writing to the sessions column in the database, what can i do to avoid this error? And what exactly is lost when this error fires?

**EDIT:**

Session table looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `sess_id` VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `sess_data` BLOB NOT NULL,
  `sess_time` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sess_lifetime` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL
) COLLATE utf8_bin, ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: what is the type (myisam, innodb, memory) of table for sessions?

Comment: The type for the sessions table is InnoDB

Comment: show the structure and keys of sessions table, pls

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EG6tSAH.png

Comment: I edited the post with the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know aws load balancer can be setup to redirect user to same ec instance, so there is no reason to share sessions.

Regarding DB session storage try to set another lock mode `PdoSessionHandler::LOCK_ADVISORY` or `PdoSessionHandler::LOCK_NONE`

Or store sessions in `memcache`